# In react-native, how to add active class to selected menu option

Tags: javascript, react-native, selecteditem

I have the following menu options in the following structure:

```
const menuOptions = [
  {
    route: 'RegisterStack',
    label: 'Register',
    size: 25,
  },
  {
    route: 'LoginStack',
    label: 'Login',
    size: 25,
  },
  {
    route: 'DashboardStack',
    label: 'Dashboard',
    size: 25,
  }
];
```

and here's my remaining code with component state and the rest of the code:

```
const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState('');
const navigation = useNavigation();

<View>
    {menuOptions.map((stack, index) => {
        return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            style={[
            styles.menuStyle, 
            index === activeLink 
                ? {backgroundColor: 'red'} 
                : {backgroundColor: 'white'}
            ]}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(stack.route)}>
            <Icon
            name={stack.icon}
            color={stack.color}
            size={stack.size}
            style={{
            marginRight: mainMenuOpen ? '10%' : 0,
            }}
            onPress={() => setActiveLink(index)}
            />
            <Text style={{width: '70%', fontWeight: '500'}}>
            {stack.label}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    })}
</View>
```

With the current code, I can see active class taking place but it seems to broke the navigation and won't route to a different page when click on it. The navigation starts working fine when I remove the following onPress method from Icon `onPress={() => setActiveLink(index)}`.

Can someone please help me how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are nesting two pressables. The touch event will be caught by `onPress of the Icon component`. This is also the reason why the navigation starts working when you remove the inner onPress function.

It seems to me that you either want `setActiveLink` to be triggered if we press on the `Icon` only or you want `setActiveLink` to be triggered and then navigate to the desired screen at the same time.

In the second case you just need one `onPress` function for the outer component.

```js
<TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            style={[
            styles.menuStyle, 
            index === activeLink 
                ? {backgroundColor: 'red'} 
                : {backgroundColor: 'white'}
            ]}
            onPress={() => {
               setActiveLink(index)
               navigation.navigate(stack.route)
            }}>
            <Icon
            name={stack.icon}
            color={stack.color}
            size={stack.size}
            style={{
            marginRight: mainMenuOpen ? '10%' : 0,
            }}
            />
            <Text style={{width: '70%', fontWeight: '500'}}>
            {stack.label}
            </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

If you want two separate things to happen, e.g. `setActiveLink` on Icon press only and `navigate` on `stack.label` press only, then you need to reorganize your component. You could create a parent view which layouts the components in a row without nesting two pressables.

```js
// you still need to apply the desired styles...
<View>
    <Pressable onPress={() => setActiveLink(index)}>
      <Icon
            name={stack.icon}
            color={stack.color}
            size={stack.size}
      />
    </Pressable>
    <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={() => {
               navigation.navigate(stack.route)
            }}>
            <Text style={{width: '70%', fontWeight: '500'}}>
                {stack.label}
            </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```